# Orchard: Master-Detail Pages

Tags: orchardcms

This is so embarrassing... things I've done literally dozens of times in classic ASP and ASP.NET...

I have  1:n master-detail tables (eg. Departments, Jobs) where

```
  Department: ID
  Marketing : 1
  Sales     : 2
  HR        : 3
```

and

```
  Job     : DepartmentID
  Job 1   : 1
  Job 2   : 2
  Job x   : 1
```

so each Department has 0 to n Jobs listed.

Now I only want a page that lists Departments. (which are links to another page)
This other page obviously presents all jobs in the chosen Department.

```
  "MASTER PAGE":          .--> "DETAILS PAGE after click on Marketing"
                          |
  Departments:            |    Jobs in Marketing
  Marketing --------------'    Job 1
  Sales --->                   Job x
  HR --->
```

Easy enough... but I have not the faintest idea how to create this in Orchard.

I have set up Taxonomies, I tried Queries...

like Taxonomy

```
  Department
        Marketing
        Sales
        HR
```

I set up a ContentType "Job", added the Tax-Field "Department" - which is fine.

I can add {Content.Fields.Job.Department}/ to Autoroute - but it does not show up in the saved Job. (slug is always .../Title-of-Job) not (.../Marketing/Title-of-Job)

And furthermore, I only get all my Jobs listed on a URL like .../Department  -- whereas I would like to get my Departments listed, not the jobs within (so this should be the "Master-page" which links to .../Department/(eg)Marketing and this one lists the jobs.

could someone please give me a detailed guide - or link - on how to accomplish this basic and trivial task for a data-driven website - in ORCHARD !?

Comment: sorry- did not know that offering $for help is forbidden - no bad intent, sorry again! (Although I wonder why..?)

Comment: The thing about autoroute is a bug: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19002 (you can vote for it). Not sure what you mean about the list of departments but you may be able to get that to work with a simple query/projection. Finally, I'd like to mention that taxonomies are just one way of doing this. There is a doc topic on relationships that may be interesting if you're ready to write some code: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations. Content Picker field is yet another way to create a relationship.